# Get object notification for Google firestore using pub/sub

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I am aware that we can publish a message to a pubsub topic when a file gets uploaded/modified in cloud Firestore using **cloud functions**.

Is there a similar way that this can we done without using Cloud Functions, like as we do it for gcs with,
**"gsutil notification create -t [pubsub_TOPIC_NAME] -f json -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://[BUCKET_NAME]"**. So that whenever a file get uploaded/modified my Subscriber will get notified.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not have a similar mechanism.  You will have to use a Cloud Functions trigger to know when a document is created, updated, or deleted.  That trigger could send a message to a pubsub topic, if you want.